# expect commands terminate too early

Tags: expect

I'm trying to write a script to automatically log into a server, run a few lines of command(to install Anaconda), and then exit. The script below executes nicely until the line `this`, which starts off fine but ends abruptly (after installing only 10 or so libraries) without giving any error message. Is it because a timeout setting for the `expect` script? Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set f [open "/Users/user1/Downloads/servers.txt"]
set hosts [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

set f [open "commands.txt"]
set commands [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

foreach host $hosts {
     spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USERNAME@$host;
     expect "?assword:"
     send "PASSWORD\r"

     foreach cmd $commands {
        expect "$ "
        send "$cmd\r"
     }

     expect "$ "
     send "exit\r"

}
```

where `servers.txt` is just a list of servers and `commands.txt` is the following:

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/anaconda.sh
bash ~/anaconda.sh -b -p $HOME/anaconda
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH"' >>~/.bash_profile
source .bash_profile
```

Comment: Note that both the `hosts` and `commands` lists will end with an empty string. You might want to use `split [read -nonewline $f] \n`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expect script set timeout = 10 automatically. So you need to change the timeout at the beginning of the script using `set timeout 120` or whatever time.

Comment: Thank you for this! The lack of error messaging on expect was unexpectedly hard to debug.. but your answer solved it for me as well.